# How can I infinitely add numbers from my createElement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I am making a calculator, and creating a new element (the number) every time I press an operator button. I'm wondering how I can get it to where I can infinitely add numbers (1+1+1+1 etc) every time i create the element. I think I'll need to store the current total number somehow, but I can't figure out how to do it. If you need any clarification let me know! Thanks
HTML

```
    <button class="numbers">0</button>
    <button class="numbers">1</button>
    <button class="numbers">2</button>
    <button class="numbers">3</button>
    <button class="numbers">4</button>
    <button class="numbers">5</button>
    <button class="numbers">6</button>
    <button class="numbers">7</button>
    <button class="numbers">8</button>
    <button class="numbers">9</button>
    <button id="addition" class="button-operator">+</button>
    <button id="equals" class="button-operator">=</button>
   <div class="result-container">
    <h1 id="value"></h1>
    <h1 id="equal"></h1>
    </div>
```

JS

```
const numbersArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.numbers'));
const addition = document.getElementById('addition');
const equal = document.getElementById('equal');
const equalSign = document.getElementById('equals');
let newValue = document.createElement('h1');

numbersArray.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        newValue.innerText = e.target.innerText;
        function resultHandler() {
            value.innerText = ''
        }

        addition.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            resultHandler()
        })
        equalSign.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            equal.innerText = parseInt(newValue.innerText) + parseInt(newValue.innerText);
            value.style.display = 'none';
            newValue.style.display = 'none';
            operator.style.display = 'none';
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: You're calling `addition.addEventListener()` and `equalSign.addEventListener()` inside your `numbersArray.forEach()` loop, which is redundant. You only need to those the event listeners once. As for calculating the result, you need to store the sequence of numbers and operators somewhere so you can build an expression (e.g. "1+4-7") but I don't see where you're storing that information. Once you do it, you can build an expression and `eval()` it to get the results.

Comment: Be aware that using `eval()` might be a security issue if you allow users to store expressions in a way that other users may retrieve. If nothing is stored once the user closes the session and there is nothing like URL parameters generating an expression, then I guess it's fine.